# Zoom to Scrollviewer Center in WPF/MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, zooming, scrollviewer

In my application I got a `ScrollViewer`, which contains a `ListBox` to display `Borders` using `Canvas`. 
ListBox `ItemSource` is bound to `ObservableCollection`, which contains borders.

Now I want to zoom to center of `ScrollViewer`. 
Binding value of slider to `ScaleX` and `ScaleY` of `Canvas.RenderTransform` was easy, but how can I bind `Scrollviewer's ViewportWidth*0.5` and `ScrollViewer's ViewportHeight*0.5` to `CenterX` or `CenterY`.

I know calculations are not possible in xaml, but I can't even bind `ViewportWidth`.
Zooming to center without MVVM is pretty easy, but I can't find a solution that works for MVVM.

```
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Canvas Width="{Binding CanvasWidth}" Height="{Binding CanvasHeight}">
                        <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="{Binding Zoomlevel,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay}" ScaleY="{Binding Zoomlevel,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay}" CenterX="{Binding ZoomCenterX, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" CenterY="{Binding ZoomCenterY, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                        </Canvas.RenderTransform>
                    </Canvas>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
```

ZoomCenterX and ZoomcenterY are properties in c# code where I calculate their values by using
 ((MainView)System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow).ContentViewer.ViewportWidth; 
I know this is really not MVVM and cheating but I couldn't find a better solution.

Comment: I'm not sure that I fully understand... why are you using a `ScrollViewer` with a `ListBox` inside, instead of just using the `ScrollViewer` that is already *inside* the `ListBox`? Then you briefly mentioned a `Slider`... where does that fit into this? Maybe if you added some XAML, it would help us to understand your problem better.

Comment: Use [converters](http://wpftutorial.net/ValueConverters.html)?

Comment: I'm new to MVVM-Pattern and i didn't know about Scrollviewer inside listbox